# Excel VBA If statements

Tags: excel, vba

Im having a little trouble with a code in excel vba.

What I want to do is that If any CELL within a RANGE on Sheet 1 is <= 2000 THEN hide a given row on Sheet 2. So it only takes 1 cell within a that range to be <= 2000 for the rows on the other sheet to be hidden. Kind of like a rotten apple spoils the bunch kind of thing.

Any help would be greatly appriciated. Thanks in Advance.

Edit: code i have that isnt working:
Edit2: code updated based on comments given, still no luck with it working.

```
Private Sub HideRows()

   Sheets("Summary").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

   For Each cell In Sheets("Worksheet").Range("G9:P9")
     If Abs(cell.Value) < 2000 Then
         Sheets("Summary").Rows(11).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Sheets("Summary").Rows(23).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Sheets("Summary").Rows(43).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Sheets("Summary").Rows(54).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Sheets("Summary").Rows(78).EntireRow.Hidden = True
         Sheets("Summary").Rows(90).EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
   Next
End Sub
```

The code does have the correct enders too such as End Select, Next, End Sub

-Matt

Comment: What's your actual code that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I went ahead and added the code im trying to work with now, the Worksheet is sheet 1 and I have the code attached to sheet 2 so I didnt add Sheets("Sheet 2") to the hidden row line

Comment: If the cells have a value of 2000 then the code to hide the rows won't execute. You need "Case Is <= 2000".

Comment: I have a few cases, 1 is for < 2000, 2 is for >= 2000, etc. But the code doesnt seem to be working. I change cells in the range given to all < 2000 on the "Worksheet" sheet and the rows arent being hidden on Sheet 2.

Comment: I think you need to specify your sheet, as you will be defaulting to ActiveSheet. Sheet2.Rows(11).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Comment: I fixed the code in my first post, still not working

Comment: Type `Option Explicit` at the top of your module (outside any procedures) and then declare all of your variables. If Alex P's answer doesn't work, it's because you have a variable problem or you're not telling us something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
Private Sub HideRows()
     Worksheets("Summary").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

     For Each cell In Sheets("Worksheet").Range("G9:P9")
        If Abs(cell) < 2000 Then
            Worksheets("Summary").Range("A11,A22,A43,A54,A78,A90").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

It's best to use the `Range` object and reference non-contiguous cells as it makes it a single line.

Answer (score 2):

You might Want to try and avoid Loops Something Like:

```
Sub NoLoopSample()
Dim lngLessThenSum As Long, lngGreaterThenSum As Long
Dim rngTestRange As Range

Set rngTestRange = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("G9:P9")

lngBetween2k4k = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngTestRange, rngTestRange, ">=" & 2000, rngTestRange, "<" & 4000)
lngLessThenSum = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rngTestRange, "<" & 2000)

If lngBetween2k4k > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Atleast 1 Number Is Between 2000 And 4000"
End If

If lngLessThenSum > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Atleast 1 Number Is Less then 2000"
    Sheets("Summary").Range("11:11, 23:23, 43:43, 54:54, 78:78, 90:90").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
```

Should do what you want and won't have to test EVERY Single cell in your range. There may be other functions or ways to do it but this was at the top of my head. Although on such a small range you shouldn't even notice the difference.

I also like to make as few changes to a worksheet from VBA as possible so in my example I hide all the rows you mention in one call rather then a call for each row.

Comment: this didnt work for me... the rows arent hiding themselves. I will have to have the scalability for more testranges too so >= 2000 and < 4000, >= 4000 and < 6000, etc.

Comment: Are you sure you had a number in the range that was less then 2000? Cause I tested this code and it worked exactly as expected. All rows ended up hidden. And to account for the other things you could use `SumIfs` in place of `SumIf`. You have an issue outside of VBA if this code didn't hide the rows when a value less then 2000. I updated my code with a Sumifs Example also.

Comment: I have code linked to sheet1 that works fine (it hides columns in both sheet 1 and 2 based on the value of a single cell on sheet 1) but for some reason the code i have linked to sheet 2 doesnt hide rows on sheet 2 based on the values of a range on sheet1

Comment: Did you copy and paste my sample and try to run it exactly as it? I have no issues while running it at all.

Comment: @user1305569 I updated my code and added a Msgbox When a number less then 2000 is found, When you run this code do you get the message box? Also, try and make a New sub the has only the 2 lines, `Sheets("Summary").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False` And `Sheets("Summary").Range("11:11, 23:23, 43:43, 54:54, 78:78, 90:90").EntireRow.Hidden = True` And see if that hides the rows or not.

Comment: Yea exactly as it is and it didnt work. I think i have a problem with how I am referencing things though. The code i have that i mentioned refers to a sell like this: If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then and based on that cells value both sheets hide columns accordingly. However if I change that target.address to = Sheets("Worksheet").Range("E3") then the sheets no longer hide columns. The sheet.range reference is correct in theory but for some reason having it like that breaks the macro. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah ok now its working, Is there any way to get that code to work in real time so that it automatically hides/unhides rows after entering a value in one of those cells?

Comment: Simply place the code under the correct worksheets change event. Seems like you have you code under the wrong Sheet's Code. Leave the ` If Target.Address = "$E$3" Then ` but place the ENTIRE thing inside of "Worksheet" Sheets' Change event. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's about EntireRow property ..

Reference .. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836836.aspx

Since your code .. `Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True` .. you have to make it sure that Row("11") is Range var ..

And to hide rows you may do `Rows(11).Hidden = True`

Comment: You were right about the rows not having the quotation marks, I edited the code based on the site you linked but still no luck. Take a look at the code change at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub try()
i = 1
While Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""
If Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value > 2000 Then
    Sheet2.Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight to the point:

```
Range("a11,a22,a43,a54,a78,a90").EntireRow.Hidden = [sum((g9:p9>0)*(g9:p9<2001))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are concerned more with the minimum value only. I would rather use Excel's Min function for the work:

```
Sub HideRows()

Set InRng = Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("G9:P9") 'Input Range
Set OutRng = Worksheets("Summary").Range("A11,A22,A43,A54,A78,A90") 'Rows to be hidden

MinVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(InRng) 'Invoking inbuilt function to get minimum value

If MinVal < 2000 Then
    OutRng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If

End Sub
```